# Use an expression as keyword in python function arguments

Tags: python, parameter-passing, apscheduler

I have to call a function in python like this

`job = scheduler.add_job(job_func, 'interval', minutes=10, id=req_json['job_id'], replace_existing=True)`

where I want to pass custom intervals like minutes/seconds/etc based on request params, so I was trying this

`job = scheduler.add_job(job_func, 'interval', interval_[1]=float(interval_[0]), id=req_json['job_id'], replace_existing=True, args=[req_json])`

where `interval_ = "10 seconds".split(' ')`

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary unpacking `**kwargs` can be used to pass keyword arguments to functions

```
kwargs = {interval_[1]: float(interval_[0])}
job = scheduler.add_job(job_func, 'interval', id=req_json['job_id'], replace_existing=True, args=[req_json], **kwargs)
```

For example

```
kwargs = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
foo(**kwargs)
```

Is equivalent to

```
foo(a=1, b=2)
```

The advantage to using this approach is that you can dynamically set the keys in a dictionary and as such can dynamically set the keyword parameters you pass to the function